# ios how to get image from collectionView cell didSelectItemAtIndexPath method from cell.contentview.subview[0]

Tags: ios, zooming

I have download this Code form this link 
http://code4app.net/ios/FullScreenImageViewController/519cbf9a6803faaf72000000
I have add image in cell like this

```
 NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[ary_UserPicture objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"StorePicturePath"]];
        if(imageURL.length != 0)
        {
            AsyncImageView *async = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 100, 100)];
            [async loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
            async.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:async];
        }
```

After that i want to zoom image according this demo link , but i am put this code in **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** this method my app crash on **vc.liftedImageView = cell.contentView.subviews[0];** on this code 
please give me solution how to get image for Zoom 
This is my code

```
- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    GGFullscreenImageViewController *vc = [[GGFullscreenImageViewController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.contentView);
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.contentView.subviews[0]);
    vc.liftedImageView = cell.contentView.subviews[0];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**The problem is How to get image in didSelectItemAtIndexPath method i have using Async image **

please share your valuable knowledge , 
Is there any other demo link for zoom image from collection view please share with me 
Thankyou .

Answer (score 0):

Here issue is because of below code.

```
if (imageURL.length != 0) {
    // Stuff to download image
}
```

From above condition we can see that if `imageURL` varialbe length is greater than 0 than only images are added in cell.

So there is a case in that you don't have valid url or url is nil (In any means condition is false). And it will be not added images to cell.

```
vc.liftedImageView = cell.contentView.subviews[0];
```

Now above line will definitely crash your application because you don't have any sub view (no images) in cell.

**Suggestion:**
Why don't you create an imageView in cell. Add `UIImageView` variable in your cell. So that when you'll get image downloaded you just set image to that imageView. Like below.

```
NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[ary_UserPicture objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"StorePicturePath"]];
if(imageURL.length != 0)
{
     AsyncImageView *async = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 100, 100)];
     [async loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
     async.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
     // [cell.contentView addSubview:async]; --> Your previous implementation         
     // Instead of adding it assign it to your cell's imageView object

     cell.imageView = async;
}
```

Rewrite code for `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` like below:

```
- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    @try {


        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // A safe check before going to access sibview.
        if ([cell.contentView.subviews count] > 0) {

            GGFullscreenImageViewController *vc = [[GGFullscreenImageViewController alloc] init];
            NSLog(@"%@",cell.contentView);

            //NSLog(@"%@",cell.contentView.subviews[0]);
            //vc.liftedImageView = cell.contentView.subviews[0];

            NSLog(@"%@",cell.imageView.image);
            vc.liftedImageView = cell.imageView.image;

            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception :%@",exception.debugDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: but i have check is not missing any image url , i can able to see images , may be problem is AsyncImageView .

Comment: @user3899589 - Instead of adding `async` image to cell you can set it to cell's imageView. I have explain in edited answer. Check and let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: cell.imageView = async; This line return a warning  and image is not add Incompatiable pointer type assigen to uiimageview to asyncImageView

Comment: What warnings you got? And how you use custom cell (or it is a `UITableViewCell`)? Have you create `UIImageView` variable in it?